# Difference between getCurrentPosition() and getPositionAt(time) in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm using Veins 4.4, OMNeT++ 5.0 and Sumo 0.25.

I use `traci->getCurrentPosition()` to get the actual position of the vehicle, i.e., `traci->getCurrentPosition().x` and `traci->getCurrentPosition().y`.

I want to estimate the position of the vehicle at a specific time in order to have some positions of the  vehicle's trajectory.

So, I use the function `traci->getPositionAt(time)` and I set `simtime_t time = simTime()+60` to get the position of the vehicle after `60 s`. But I get the current position!

What is the difference between `getCurrentPosition()` and `getPositionAt(time)`?

How can I get some position of the vehicle's trajectory?

Answer (score 1):

Below you have all the implementations of the functions you have mentioned. As you can see in the first case the comment for `getPositionAt()` says:

> It is intended to be passed `simTime()` as `actualTime` and returns the
>   actual position.

Seems like these functions do not cover your case at all.

---

You can see how these functions work at `Move.h`. The comments are detailed enough too

```
/**
 * @brief Returns the position of the Move (Host) at the specified point in time.
 * It is intended to be passed simTime() as actualTime and returns the actual position.
 *
 * Assumes that direction represents a normalized vector (length equals 1.0).
 * Further this function does not check whether the given time point is before
 * the startTime of the actual move pattern. So in this case one might obtain
 * an unintended result.
 *
 */
virtual Coord getPositionAt(simtime_t_cref actualTime = simTime()) const
{
    // if speed is very close to 0.0, the host is practically standing still
    if ( FWMath::close(speed, 0.0) ) return startPos;

    // otherwise: actualPos = startPos + ( direction * v * t )
    return startPos + ( direction * speed * SIMTIME_DBL(actualTime - startTime) );
}
virtual const Coord& getCurrentPosition() const
{
    if (lastPos.z != DBL_MAX)
        return lastPos;
    return startPos;
}
```

---

`getPositionAt()` is also implemented at `TraCIMobility.h` as:

```
    virtual Coord getPositionAt(const simtime_t& t) const {
        return move.getPositionAt(t) ;
    }
```

---

and `getCurrentPosition()` is implemented at `BaseMobility.h` as:

```
/** @brief Returns the current position at the current simulation time. */
virtual Coord getCurrentPosition(/*simtime_t_cref stWhen = simTime()*/) const {
    //return move.getPositionAt(stWhen);
    return move.getStartPos();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your clear response.
I know the vehicle trajectory as follow: 
list<string>list=traciVehicle->getPlannedRoadIds();
string lanedeparture,lanearrival; 
lanedeparture=list.front();
lanearrival=list.back();
But I still can’t get the position of the vehicle's trajectory for many timesteps like in the FCD file  http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Output/FCDOutput

Comment: Your comment seems to be a different question. Kindly ask this in a separate topic if you can